# Swipe ViewGroup with view pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Is there anyway to swipe 'ViewGroups' with 'ViewPager'?
I want to swipe one 'LinearLayout' with another 'LinearLayout' on 'Button' click.
If anyone knows the solution.Please Help

Comment: Am I correctly understand you, do you want to programmatically set the page of view pager?

Comment: Yes.But instead of fragments,i want to swipe Views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way(as I know) to swipe views with ViewPager, but you can use [ViewFlipper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html), which is like ViewPager but for views.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your suggestion.i have done what i want with view flipper :)